# Php, how to remove characters after asterisk and stop at file extension

Tags: php, mysql, regex, sql-update

I have this following images in my MYSQL database and I want to search and replace for all occurences following the pattern (everything including the asterisk * has to go but the file extension needs to stay - the number of characters after the * varies, the same for the extension.) 
Thanks for your help in advance!

**This is what I have:**

mo051316hires-5*100xx2304-2304-576-0.jpg

brandicourt-photo-high-res-1*100xx3264-3264-816-0.gif

**This is what I want:**

mo051316hires-5.jpg

brandicourt-photo-high-res-1.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` like this:

```
$newFileName = preg_replace('/\*[^.]+/', '', $oldFileName);
```

This looks for a literal `*` (`\*`) and one or more non-period characters (`[^.]+`) and replaces them with an empty string.

[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/uQ0Yi)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to include this in a mysql query (search and replace)?

Comment: @user1564379 Because you tagged this with [tag:php] and wrote, "PHP, how to," in your title, I didn't realize you were trying to do this in a MySQL query, rather than in PHP code. I'd be happy to explain how to do that, but that's a very different kind of solution. You might consider asking it as a new question and posting a link here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

To fix existing data, using MySQL:

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '*', 1),
            '.',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.', -1)
    FROM ...
```

If it looks good, the put it in

```
UPDATE ...
    SET col = CONCAT ...
```